# Text and image stopped being mobile responsive

Tags: html, css

Been trying to figure that out for hours but couldn't wrap my head around it.
Really appreciate some help here!

Not sure if it was something to do with "display:flex"?

Code:
https://github.com/louisecchan/cakeday-countdown

These are the parts that I think are relevant for the screw-up.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.coming-soon {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}

.countdown {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Recoleta", serif;
}
```

I tried to look at whether it was something to do "justify-content" and "display: flex" before - but those changes didn't work.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Lou, welcome to stackoverflow. It would be really great if you can share more detail on your issue. What you are trying to build. what issue you are facing in that and create the minimum reproducible snippet of your issue.

Comment: Was it responsive before? What changes you made?

Comment: Yes it was responsive before. I changed the .countdown section's "justify-content" from "space-around" to "center". Might have accidentally deleted one line or two as well. @Usaid

Comment: Hi, appreciate the advice a lot. I have updated the question with the code snippets now. @Master.Deep

Comment: You probably removed `flex-wrap: wrap` on `.countdown`. Except for that you do not have any media queries or anything else that can make it responsive. Only the main heading is responsive because you have given it a relative font-size.

Comment: @Usaid Hey it works again now! Thank you SO SO MUCH!!! Appreciate that a lot.